# Kernel of Cotangent Vector Equals Tangent Space to Submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

Given a $1$-form $\omega=dx+ydz$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$, does there exist a $2$-dimensional submanifold $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$\ker(\omega_p)=T_pS$$
for all $p\in S$?

This is a homework question on which I have been stuck for quite a while. How should one determine the kernel of a covector $\omega_p$ given a general $1$-form $\omega$? I know that if $S$ is the preimage of a regular value of some smooth map $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$, then $T_pS=\ker(T_pF)$. So in this case can I conclude that
$$\ker(\omega_p)=T_pS\quad \forall p\in S\iff \omega_p=T_pF\quad \forall p\in S$$
or is the above not so obvious/false?

If $\omega=df$ (i.e. when it is exact) though, we do know that $\omega_p$ is the map
$$T_pf:T_p\mathbb{R}^3\to T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$$

But now I'm totally lost since $S$ need not be the preimage of a regular value of $f$. I suspect that the answer to the original problem is no when $\omega$ is not exact. Can anyone give a hint on how to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If this is a homework question, maybe you should look up Frobenius' theorem.

Comment: @WillieWong But Frobenius theorem has not been covered in our lectures and thus I'm not sure whether it is legitimate to apply the theorem (which I need to thoroughly understand in the first place) to solve this exercise.

Comment: In a course where Frobenius hasn't been covered, I would follow the answer of [Ted Shifrin](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2731640/1543). The computation he gave is the one that motivates the statement of Frobenius' theorem.

Comment: I would like to encourage you to read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735385/need-help-understanding-this-example-of-a-distribution), it helps to get a grip on what is going on geometrically.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a more basic argument. *Locally*, any smooth surface $S\subset\Bbb R^3$ is in fact of the form $f=0$ for some smooth function $f$ (having $0$ a regular value). Thus, *locally*, we would have to have $df = \lambda\omega$ for some nonvanishing function $\lambda$. So, can we *locally* have $df = \lambda(dx+y\,dz)$?

There are various ways to proceed, but perhaps the easiest is to note that this tells us that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \lambda, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \lambda y.$$
In particular, $0=\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial\lambda}{\partial y}$ and so $$0=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z\partial y}= \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial z} = \lambda + y\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial y} = \lambda.$$
This is an obvious contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I just realized that sometimes [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229794/implicit-function-theorem-and-submanifolds-in-mathbbrn) is regarded as the defining property of a submanifold. In my class we use the coordinate chart definition. Could you please elaborate on why such $\lambda$ exists locally given our assumption on kernel of cotangent vectors?

Comment: Because you have a one-dimensional vector space at each point, so if you have two nonzero elements, one is a nonzero scalar times the other. The fact that $0$ is a regular value says that $df\ne 0$ as a $1$-form on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that you have essentially shown that if $\omega$ is not closed, then there is not (hyper)surface $S$ such that $\ker(\omega_p) = T_pS$ for all $p \in S$ (unless I misunderstood something).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: No, I've shown that no (nowhere-zero) function multiple of $\omega$ isn't closed (locally exact). This is, of course, equivalent to failure of the Frobenius condition $d\omega\wedge\omega = 0$.

Comment: So I did misunderstand something. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @TedShifrin could you elaborate a bit more on why we can write $df = \lambda w$ please? I don't quite get your vector space explanation... I mean what I can see is that $ker(df_p) = ker(w_p) = T_p S$, but how could this lead straight to $df = \lambda w$ locally? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Longti: The annihilator of $T_pS$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $T^*_p\Bbb R^3$ (e.g., because $T_pS\subset T_p\Bbb R^3$ is $2$-dimensional), and $df_p$ and $\omega_p$ are nonzero elements, hence differ by a nonzero scalar multiple.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I need to review some linear algebra..

Answer (score 3):

To give some insight on what is to follow, let us notice that $\omega$ is a contact form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that any integral submanifold of $\ker(\omega)$ has dimension at most $1$. I am basically going to prove this result.

First, notice that $\mathrm{d}\omega=\mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}z$ is non-degenerate (as a bilinear form) on $\ker(\omega)$, indeed one has:
$$\omega\wedge\mathrm{d}\omega=\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}z\neq 0.$$
Notice that if $S$ is an integral submanifold of $\ker(\omega)$ and $p\in S$, then $\omega_{\vert S}=0$ and $\mathrm{d}\omega_{\vert S}=0$, meaning that $T_pS$ is an isotropic subvector space of the [symplectic vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space) $(\ker(\omega_p),\mathrm{d}{\omega_p}_{\vert\ker(\omega_p)})$, so that:
$$\dim T_pS\leqslant\dim(T_pS)^\perp=2-\dim T_pS,$$
and $T_pS$ has at most dimension $1$ and so does $S$.

This proof is just a matter of linear algebra, there is nothing more to it. Notice that it is crucial to know that the bilinear form is non-degenerate to compute the dimension of the orthogonal.

**Reminders.** Here are the relevant definitions.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $B\colon V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear form.

> **Definitions.** Let $E$ be a subvector space of $V$, then $E^\perp:=\{v\in V:\forall w\in E,B(v,w)=0\}$, $E$ is said to be isotropic whenever $E\subset E^\perp$ and $B$ is non-degenerate when $\ker(B):=V^\perp=\{0\}$.

The main result used is that when $B$ is non-degenerate, then $\dim E^\perp=\dim V-\dim E$.

Let us define the linear map $u\colon V\rightarrow E^*$ by $u(v)=B(v,\cdot)$, its kernel is given by $E^\perp$ and its image is $E^*$. Indeed, since $B$ is non-degenerate and $V$ is finite-dimensional, $v\in V\rightarrow B(v,\cdot)\in V^*$ is an isomorphism. Whence the result, using the rank-nullity theorem.

A symplectic vector space is a vector space endowed with a non-degenerate skew-symmetric bilinear form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I have to say that I feel so stupid (and a bit discouraged, mainly because of myself) right now since never before have I heard of most of those terminologies (which might be really basic), e.g. contact form, isotropy and symplectic vector space. I will upvote this answer when I have enough reputation points and will come back to accept it only when I fully understand what is really going on. Thank you again!

Comment: Do not feel stupid, this is really just a matter of terminology (I am going to add the definitions) and there is not much going on, I promise! Besides, the first sentence about contact form is not really relevant, I couldn't help but pointing it out since this is my area of research.

Comment: Thanks for the augmentation! I got the proof of the last part but the initial argument is not so clear to me. Please correct me if I misunderstood anything. To check that the bilinear form $d\omega:\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^3)\times \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^3)\to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$ restricted to $\ker(\omega)\times \ker(\omega)$ is non-degenerate, let $X,Y\in \ker(\omega)$ be given. We know that $d\omega(X,Y)=0$ and that $\omega(X)=\omega(Y)=0$. We have to show that $X=Y=\{0\}$. But how is that related to the wedge product of $\omega$ and $d\omega$ being non-zero?

Comment: This is again a matter of linear algebra, you can see a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583042/alternative-definition-for-contact-manifold/2583306#2583306). This is the contraposition of the emphasized proposition.